# Building hybrid mobile application using ionic and facing hardware back button issues

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am developing mobile application using ionic. The problem I am facing that when I click hardware back button, it lands me to the menu screen and I want dialog box to appear which shows me "Are you sure you want to exit?", though I have added code for that which is working only when I touch anywhere in my application but if I don't touch anywhere it lands me to the menu screen which I want to avoid as I wanted to show the dialog box on clicking back button. How can I achieve this? I have added this code in my login, dashboard and welcome pages in Component.ts file.  Here is the code below:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {

this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
  if (this.routerOutlet && this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
    this.routerOutlet.pop();
  } else if (this.router.url === '/login' || this.router.url === '/dashboard'
    || this.router.url === '/welcome') {
    var exitSure = confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    if (exitSure) {
      navigator['app'].exitApp();
      
    }
  } else {
    this.location.back();
  }
});
```

}

Comment: `Developing mobile application using ionic?` this doesn't describe your question at all, you should use a more descriptive title to help others understand what you're asking

Comment: ok, let me edit the title again but the body is understandable right?

Comment: yip, usually people use a heading like yours when they're asking about whether or not they should be using ionic and those are the questions which get closed, so that's the only reason why i'm here :)

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the title, now could you plz help me to make this question reach to the ones who are aware of this issue. It would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe helps you.
The dialog box only shows at login page, dashboard page, welcome page only.
**app.component.ts**

```
 initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
     if (this.router.isActive('/login', true) && this.router.url === '/login') {
       //Your dialog box Cod
       navigator['app'].exitApp();
     } else if (this.router.isActive('/dashboard', true) && this.router.url === '/dashboard') {
       //Your dialog box Cod
       navigator['app'].exitApp();
     } else if (this.router.isActive('/welcome', true) && this.router.url === '/welcome') {
       //Your dialog box Cod
       navigator['app'].exitApp();
     }
   });
 });
}
```